# how could the df command show the right mounts?

Tags: linux, mount, bind-mount

Under redhat 7, given this fstab where a "bind mount" across file systems is defined:

```
/dev/mapper/datab_vg-lv_db    /appli/postgres    xfs    defaults   0 0
/appli/postgres/var           /var/postgres      none   bind       0 0
```

`df -k` is showing its values `(1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on)` relative to the wrong path. (`/var/postgres` instead of `/appli/postgres`):

> /dev/mapper/datab_vg-lv_db  176594692 34629472 141965220  20% /var/postgres

How to get the right result using df or any alternative command ?

Comment: What makes you think that `/var/postgres` is the *wrong* path?

Comment: I consider /var/postgres a wrong path because it doesn't point to a logical volume, off wich df is aimed to chow the size . (my aim is to see the used size of logical volumes with a path identifying it)